# A more efficient / less-amateur way to do something based on selected option instead of a massive if-tree?

Tags: c#, list, loops, if-statement, resources

This has been bugging me for a while but I'm not sure if there's anyway to improve this... Basically in this project I have a list compiled of cards that I want to add to a final text output. I iterate through the list and every iteration I go through many if statements, checking for a card name and if the card name is recognizable then I add a block of code to a string that is specific to that card. Here are some things that might help / restrict solutions:

- The blocks of code that get added to the string that I'm compiling are stored in the resources file of my project. You will see in the code below they're referred to as m1735xxxx. Maybe there's a way to do a search through these strings in my resource file much like a list?
- all of the possible items on the list being read in are known and have a block of code that goes with them stored in my resources.

Code:

```
int numCards = moduleList.Count;
while (moduleList.Any())
{
    SplashScreen.SetProgress((int)((numCards - moduleList.Count) * 100.00 / numCards));
    if (moduleList[0].name.Contains("1756"))
    {
        etrCount++;
        string newCard = Cards.m1756EN2T.Replace("@SLOT@", etrCount.ToString());
        newCard = newCard.Replace("@ETHERNUM@", etrCount.ToString());
        finalOutput = finalOutput + newCard;
        finalOutput += Environment.NewLine;
        finalOutput += Environment.NewLine;
        moduleList.RemoveAt(0);
        modSlotCount = 0;
    }
    else if (moduleList[0].name.Contains("AENTR"))
    {
        aentrCount++;
        modSlotCount = 0;
        string newCard = Cards.m1734AENTR.Replace("@SLOT@", modSlotCount.ToString());
        newCard = newCard.Replace("@SIZE@", numMods[aentrCount].ToString());
        newCard = newCard.Replace("@AENTRNUM@", aentrCount.ToString());
        newCard = newCard.Replace("@ETHERNUM@", etrCount.ToString());
        finalOutput = finalOutput + newCard;
        finalOutput += Environment.NewLine;
        finalOutput += Environment.NewLine;
        moduleList.RemoveAt(0);
        modSlotCount++;
    }
    while (moduleList.Any() && !moduleList[0].name.Contains("AENTR") && !moduleList[0].name.Contains("1756"))
    {
        if (moduleList[0].name == "1734-IB8S")
        {
            string newCard = Cards.m1734IB8S.Replace("@SLOT@", modSlotCount.ToString());
            newCard = newCard.Replace("@AENTRNUM@", aentrCount.ToString());
            finalOutput = finalOutput + newCard;
            finalOutput += Environment.NewLine;
            finalOutput += Environment.NewLine;
            moduleList.RemoveAt(0);
            modSlotCount++;
        }
        else if (moduleList[0].name == "1734-OB8S")
        {
            string newCard = Cards.m1734OB8S.Replace("@SLOT@", modSlotCount.ToString());
            newCard = newCard.Replace("@AENTRNUM@", aentrCount.ToString());
            finalOutput = finalOutput + newCard;
            finalOutput += Environment.NewLine;
            finalOutput += Environment.NewLine;
            moduleList.RemoveAt(0);
            modSlotCount++;
        }
        else if (moduleList[0].name == "1734-IB4D")
        {
            string newCard = Cards.m1734IB4D.Replace("@SLOT@", modSlotCount.ToString());
            newCard = newCard.Replace("@AENTRNUM@", aentrCount.ToString());
            finalOutput = finalOutput + newCard;
            finalOutput += Environment.NewLine;
            finalOutput += Environment.NewLine;
            moduleList.RemoveAt(0);
            modSlotCount++;
        }
        else if (moduleList[0].name == "1734-OB4E")
        {
            string newCard = Cards.m1734OB4E.Replace("@SLOT@", modSlotCount.ToString());
            newCard = newCard.Replace("@AENTRNUM@", aentrCount.ToString());
            finalOutput = finalOutput + newCard;
            finalOutput += Environment.NewLine;
            finalOutput += Environment.NewLine;
            moduleList.RemoveAt(0);
            modSlotCount++;
        }
        else if (moduleList[0].name == "1734-IE2C")
        {
            string newCard = Cards.m1734IE2C.Replace("@SLOT@", modSlotCount.ToString());
            newCard = newCard.Replace("@AENTRNUM@", aentrCount.ToString());
            finalOutput = finalOutput + newCard;
            finalOutput += Environment.NewLine;
            finalOutput += Environment.NewLine;
            moduleList.RemoveAt(0);
            modSlotCount++;
        }
        else if (moduleList[0].name == "1734-OE2C")
        {
            string newCard = Cards.m1734OE2C.Replace("@SLOT@", modSlotCount.ToString());
            newCard = newCard.Replace("@AENTRNUM@", aentrCount.ToString());
            finalOutput = finalOutput + newCard;
            finalOutput += Environment.NewLine;
            finalOutput += Environment.NewLine;
            moduleList.RemoveAt(0);
            modSlotCount++;
        }
        else if (moduleList[0].name == "1734-IR2")
        {
            string newCard = Cards.m1734IR2.Replace("@SLOT@", modSlotCount.ToString());
            newCard = newCard.Replace("@AENTRNUM@", aentrCount.ToString());
            finalOutput = finalOutput + newCard;
            finalOutput += Environment.NewLine;
            finalOutput += Environment.NewLine;
            moduleList.RemoveAt(0);
            modSlotCount++;
        }
    }
}
```

See what I mean by amateur style? This works it's just really ugly to look at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a dictionary which maps your strings to the resource field names and lookup the card via the resource manager:

```
var mappings = new Dictionarx<string, string> { { "1734-IB8S", "m1734IB8S" }, { "1734-OB8S", "m1734OB8S" } /* ... */ }
var resourceManager = new ResourceManager("yourresourcefilename", typeof(Cards).Assembly);

while (moduleList.Any() && !moduleList[0].name.Contains("AENTR") && !moduleList[0].name.Contains("1756"))
{
    string resourceName;
    if (!mappings.TryGetValue(moduleList[0].name, out resourceName))
    {
        continue;
    }

    var field = resourceManager.GetString(resourceName);
    string newCard = field.Replace("@SLOT@", modSlotCount.ToString());
    newCard = newCard.Replace("@AENTRNUM@", aentrCount.ToString());
    finalOutput = finalOutput + newCard;
    finalOutput += Environment.NewLine;
    finalOutput += Environment.NewLine;
    moduleList.RemoveAt(0);
    modSlotCount++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the replace functionality is not always the same simple 'replace'.

You could create a dictionary of module names, and each key in that dictionary refers to a function that does the actual replace for that key, like:

```
Dictionary<string, Func<string, string>> functions = ...;
```

Then you can avoid all these if-statements; and merely find the correct key in the dictionary based on `moduleList[0].name`, and execute the associated replace function.

Comment: I like this idea but then won't I have an ugly large dictionary declaration + functions for each card? There may be 30-40 of these cards and this will just be replacing one ugly block of code with another.

Comment: Indeed, but all definitions will be in one place and you don't have duplicate code. Easy to maintain as well. If you need to add one, you simply add a new item in the dictionary.

Comment: so I take it there's no way to do something like: "foreach (string item in resources) { // do my comparisons }"